# How do I Convert [AnonymousType#1] or pre-define it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-3.5

I get this Error

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<object>'
```

Running 3.5 .net Never had this issue before. not sure what was changed.

the error happens on line **select new { ITEMID = p.PRESSRELEASEID };**

i have tried but keep getting different convert errors.

```
StringBuilder textStr = new StringBuilder();

var years = (from ys in db.tblPressReleases orderby ys.prdate descending select ys.prdate.Year).Distinct();

ddlYear.DataSource = years;
ddlYear.DataBind();
ddlYear.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Year", ""));

IQueryable<object> pressreleases ;
DateTime startdate, enddate;

if (this.iFilterMonth != null && this.iFilterMonth > 0 && this.iFilterYear != null)
{
    startdate = new DateTime((int)this.iFilterYear, (int)this.iFilterMonth, 1);
    enddate = startdate.AddMonths(1);

    pressreleases = from p in db.tblPressReleases
                    where p.prdate.Date >= startdate.Date && p.prdate.Date < enddate.Date
                    orderby p.prdate descending
                    select new { ITEMID = p.PRESSRELEASEID };
}
else if (this.iFilterYear != null)
{
    startdate = new DateTime((int)this.iFilterYear, 1, 1);
    enddate = new DateTime((int)this.iFilterYear + 1, 1, 1);

    pressreleases = from p in db.tblPressReleases
                    where p.prdate.Date >= startdate.Date && p.prdate.Date < enddate.Date
                    orderby p.prdate descending
                    select new { ITEMID = p.PRESSRELEASEID };
}
else
{
    pressreleases = (from p in db.tblPressReleases
                    orderby p.prdate descending
                    select new { ITEMID = p.PRESSRELEASEID }).Take(15);
}

dlDisplay.DataSourceID = "";
dlDisplay.DataSource = pressreleases;
dlDisplay.Visible = true;
dlDisplay.DataBind();
```

Comment: @JonSkeet: v3.5 (see tags, though _you_ should know that... ;-)

Comment: @BradChristie: Yup, I just noticed that :)

Comment: @BradChristie: Note that using v3.5 means no `dynamic`...

Comment: Oh, touché good sir. Ironic I called you out on versioning and missed the boat myself. ...I deserve that. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three independent options:

- Ditch the anonymous type entirely. You've only got a single value, so why not use `select p.PRESSRELEASEID`?
- Cast in the `select` clause:

  ```
  select (object) new { ITEMID = p.PRESSRELEASEID }
  ```
- Declare the variable using `var`, providing a dummy example:

  ```
  var pressreleases = new[] { new { ITEMID = "" } }.ToQueryable();
  ```

As an aside, I would strongly advise reconsidering your naming - both in terms of VERYSHOUTY names and veryquiet names; more conventional names would be `pressReleases` (for a local variable) and `PressReleaseID` (for a property).

Comment: being a beginner, I thought this query is made for rowview which returns more than one?, question for the 2nd option, (object) will be what I want the return type to be correct?

Comment: @vico: I'm not sure I understand what the first part of your comment means. For the second part, what return type are you talking about? The code you've shown doesn't declare a method or have any return statements, so I'm not sure what return type you mean.

Comment: I tried #2 before posting this but always get "Type expected"

Comment: @vico: That's not enough information on its own - I suspect you're getting a lot more context than that, including *where* the error occurs. Just adding the cast within the `select` clause should be okay.

Comment: sorry for all the trouble. I am not good in .net, trying to apply this fix is getting me more confused with the new errors that came out.. (and I can't just upgrade to 4.0) to make this thing simpler

Comment: @vico: Is there anyone within your company who may be able to help you apply the suggested changes? Stack Overflow doesn't really work as an interactive debugging tool :(